# Opencv_createsamples fails with segmentation fault

Tags: linux, opencv, image-recognition, training-data, haar-classifier

I am currently trying to make a HAAR classifier. I have made an annotation file and have done everything as described in the official openCV tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html . 
However, when I try to create the samples with opencv_createsamples, I get an error. My command:

`opencv_createsamples -vec /some_dirs/samples/samples.vec -info /some_dirs/annotations/annotations.dat -w 8 -h 8 -num 100`

The error:

`Info file name: /home/nikifaets/code/pointsProcessing/annotations/annotations.dat
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: /home/nikifaets/code/pointsProcessing/samples/samples.vec
BG  file name: (NULL)
Num: 100
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 8
Height: 8
Max Scale: -1
RNG Seed: 12345
Create training samples from images collection...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in resize, file /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp, line 4044
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv/src/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize`

Aborted (core dumped)

However, if I try to do only two samples (no idea why exactly 2...), it runs and creates the .vec file, although my dataset includes about 300-400 pictures.

Pastebin of [annotations.dat](https://pastebin.com/kQuLnzuq)

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: maybe one of your images is damaged or not present or annotation illegal? Can you try to split your annotations by half and test on both files srparately? If it fails only on one of them, split that one again by half, and so on. Should be the fastest way to find the not working images (without changing the code)

Comment: Yup! Problem solved. To be honest did not expect to have such kind of problem. The first image from the annotations file had the description of point of interest *0 0 0 0*, which is invalid. Thank you very much for pointing that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thank to Micka for suggesting a solution and being right. There was an error in the annotations file. One of the descriptions of a point of interest was *0 0 0 0* which is invalid. Always check your files carefully!