# opencv_createsamples errors out (Segmentation fault: 11)

Tags: macos, opencv, fault

I'm going to create a Haar Cascade Classifier.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

I have installed OpenCV on my Mac OS Catalina, and run the following command to create positive samples. But it errors out.

*opencv_createsamples -img polo135x135.jpg -bg bg2.txt -info info/info.lst -pngoutput info -num 568*

My opencv version is "opencv-3.4.9". I used this instead of the latest version, because the latest version doesn't create "opencv_createsamples" after cmake/build.

Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: can you show parts of your bg list file? Can you try to reduce the list and use a mimal scrnario which works? Then try zo identify whether there are bad/missing images in that list.

Comment: The bg.txt file has images path like the followings:

neg2/1409.jpg
neg2/1353.jpg
neg2/1435.jpg

And I tried with the shorter bg file, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: are you very sure how opencv_createsamples uses the relative pathes? Is the folder  neg2 in the same folder als opencv_createsamples? is polo135x135.jpg in the same folder as opencv_createsamples? Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141708/opencv-createsamples-fails-with-segmentation-fault and other google results?

Comment: Hi Micka, I used full path for both the command and bg.txt content. It doesn't work at all.